# Unable to install new software or update the OS and sudo apt-get -f install fails

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, updates

Output of `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcdaudio1 libenca0 libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libqt5clucene5 libqt5help5
  libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5xmlpatterns5 libslv2-9 libx265
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-75-generic musescore-common
  qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libkmod2:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libkmod2:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
90 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 136 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 306522 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libkmod2_22-1ubuntu5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libkmod2:i386 (22-1ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libkmod2_22-1ubuntu5_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libkmod2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libkmod2:i386
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libkmod2_22-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy libkmod2 libkmod2:i386`? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:

*sudo apt autoremove*

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get upgrade -f

Then:

*sudo dpkg --configure -a*

sudo apt-get -f install

Hope it helps, greetings. :=)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This a try-to-catch-all shot in the dark and doesn't address the actual issue. -1